# Opaqueness of YAML parsing process and expected behavior with live patching of the parser

Tags: yaml, specifications

According to the YAML specification, it seems like the authors wanted to put a clear distinction between the data/content, and the "metadata" (tag names, anchor names, etc).
For example, they warn multiple times to avoid interfering the data by using directives like `!` or others, and that the parser should forget the preprocessing names immediately after finish parsing.

Having said that, I thought if it's also mandatory to keep the parser's behavior constant, static, for the whole parsing period of a single document? For example, YAML supports custom/user-defined/local tags. But what if I load/add new supported tags dynamically at runtime, while some document processing is taking place? Is it okay to allow the parser to change its behavior when encountering the same tag, first time as undefined one, but after some seconds, treat the same tag correctly as the parsing extension has been installed? Something like Loadable Kernel Modules, or Live Patching in Linux Kernel.

And, in case it's not restricted by specification, yet we may encounter implementation gaps. So, does the implementations of libyaml in the wild support this behavior, or may crash or produce problematic behavior in this end-case?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, *tags* are, for your intents and purposes, not thrown away or „forgotten“ immediately, but preserved up until the [representation graph](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#321-representation-graph). That sets them apart from anchors & aliases which can be discarded earlier.

The parser is not generally concerned with processing tags. Sure, if you're using `%TAG` directives or even just the predefined `!!` and `!` shorthands,  the parser might replace them (some do, some don't), but interpreting what e.g. `!!str` actually means happens at a later stage.

YAML defines [schemas](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-10-recommended-schemas):

> A YAML schema is a combination of a set of tags and a mechanism for resolving non-specific tags.

Even this only brings you so far as to have specific tags on every node in the document. The binding of tags to implementation-specific types (e.g. from a YAML `!!map` to a Python `dict`) happens in the *construction* step, which is not thoroughly defined in the specification and implementations deviate quite a lot from each other here.

I would say the specification strongly implies, without saying it, that a schema shall be constant for the duration of the document loading process, and that *supporting a schema* means to be able to load all tags defined in the schema into native types.

Changing the behavior of construction during loading is not at all like live patching or loading a kernel module, because loading data is a very different use-case from operating a kernel that may run for a long time. As a user, I would expect a deserializer such as YAML to guarantee *consistency* of the data it loads, and that breaks when you start modifying the behavior during processing.

Also if at some point a tag is unknown, *loading fails* (see [Loading Failure Points](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#33-loading-failure-points)). Doesn't matter if the tag is available later. If, however, you want to initially have the tag `!foo` do one thing, but later on another thing… there is sadly no wording in the spec that explicitly forbids this, but at least the description of recommended schemas implies that tags shall always load into the same structures. I also see absolutely no reason to do that, unless you explicitly want to break the YAML implementation.

libyaml isn't concerned with the construction step at all, therefore it won't have a problem with this. Generally, if an implementation provides construction and doesn't explicitly state that doing this is okay, I would not count on it.

Frankly, I wonder what your use-case is and whether it wouldn't be far simpler to use a mutex to ensure that the loading semantics are only changed *between* documents.